# Converting between PointT and PointXYZ

Tags: oop, templates, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have compiled and run this 
https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/apps/src/openni_ii_normal_estimation.cpp

However I now want to be able to access the underlying raw information about the normals and x,y,z points. However, I cannot seem to extract raw information (x,y,z positions for example) from the CloudConstPtr (that's pcl::PointCloud::ConstPtr).

I have tried casting to new PointCloud objects of template type PointXYZ but this isn't valid. Can somebody please demonstrate how to extract xyz information? It should be easy.

Comment: Show us the exact code you're using. And keep in mind that there is no such thing as an actual PointT. It's a template parameter. It in itself is not a real object. P.s. don't use the PCL tag. It is not related to the PointClouds Library.

Answer (score 1):

Dou you want to **access** or **extract** the XYZ info? (i cannot try to run the code at this moment, but is should be easy, indeed)

If you want to access it, you can find it in the `points` attribute of your cloud object, eg.:

```
cloud->points[pointNumber].x
cloud->points[pointNumber].y
cloud->points[pointNumber].z
```

(assuming that cloud variable is a pointer)

If you want to extract it to a separate point cloud or data type, you just simply loop over it and copy the `points` data to your separate object/variable. Or just simply use the

```
pcl::copyPointCloud()
```

internal function to copy it into another PCL cloud type (see API doc for details, it can be found in the `common` namespace).